# How to restore the state of previous activity when back arrow is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I have a `activity` Home which has a `fragment`. I am trying to restore the state of `activity` when user come back to Home.

That's the method of Home `Activity` which store the instance of fragment to `Bundle`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"fragment",feedFragment);
}
```

And i have this check `onCreate` in `HomeActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    context = this;
    initUi();
    initToolbar();
    initFragment(savedInstanceState);
}

private void initFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        feedFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState,"fragment");

    }else{
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_container, feedFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

So the problem is when i change orientation of screen when i am in HomeActivity. It restore it states. But when i am in some other activity and i come back to home activity from Back arrow in actionbar of another activity. then it doesn't restore it states it start loading data from server again.
What am i doing wrong? how can i restore the prevoius state when i navigate back to HomeActivity from Back arrow in action bar

Comment: When i press device's back button then all goes well but when i press back arrow in action bar to go back to previous screen it start reloading data

Comment: Use `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {` not `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {`, also did you implement `UP` navigation on your arrow button on the action bar?

Comment: What's the up navigation?

Comment: this http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: i tired adding   NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);   but this doesn't work it reloads the screen again

Answer (score 1):

You mus use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods.
Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android?rq=1) so you can find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

please in your manifest file inside the activity element of your HomeActivity     put  android:launchMode = "singleTop"